# Oracle pl/sql permutation and combination

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am not sure what is the correct search term for this, please let me know if there's already an answer for this.
eg:
I have these data

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

What is the best way to calculate the addition of each possible combination? Such as:

```
A
A+B
A+C
A+D
A+E
A+B+C
A+B+D
A+B+E
A+C+D
A+C+E
A+C+D+E
A+B+C+D
A+B+C+E
A+B+C+D+E
B
B+C
B+D
B+E
B+C+D
B+C+E
B+C+D+E
C
C+D
C+E
...
The list goes on.......
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

The 5 data are not fixed. I might have 10.. 20 or 50 or 1000 :(

Thank you.

Comment: Are you just trying to do a count of possible combinations? That's a well known formula and does not need any SQL. Or are you trying to actually enumerate every possible combination?

Comment: Hello, no I am not trying to do just a count of possible combinations. I need the result of each combination

Comment: Why would you need something like this? Your server won't be able to handle it. The table would be practically unusable

Comment: have you tried regular expression?

Comment: @vishnusable I'm not sure what a regular expression has to do with the question at all...

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you can almost do this with this set of `left join`s:

```
select (t1.col + coalesce(t2.col, 0) + coalesce(t3.col, 0) +
        coalesce(t4.col, 0) + coalesce(t5.col, 0)
       ) as sumcombo
from t t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.col < t2.col left join
     t t3
     on t2.col < t3.col left join
     t t4
     on t3.col < t4.col left join
     t t5
     on t4.col < t5.col;
```

It doesn't quite work, because you can never get just "A" for instance.  Instead:

```
with t as (
      select col
      from table
      union all
      select NULL
      from dual
     )
select (t1.col + coalesce(t2.col, 0) + coalesce(t3.col, 0) +
        coalesce(t4.col, 0) + coalesce(t5.col, 0)
       ) as sumcombo
from table t1 left join
     t t2
     on t1.col < t2.col or t2.col is null left join
     t t3
     on t2.col < t3.col or t3.col is null left join
     t t4
     on t3.col < t4.col or t4.col is null left join
     t t5
     on t4.col < t5.col or t5.col is null;
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't state clearly in my question. The number of data is not fixed :(. I might have 10 or 20 or 50 or 1000 rows

Comment: Listing all the permutations of 1000 elements is not going to happen in my lifetime.

Comment: Yea I know. Even 50 elements will return 3*10^64 results, which is ridiculous. Is there anyway flexible way to do from stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved by a hierarchical query. First of all, build a further child column `col2` for connection:

```
-- your test data set
with testdata as
 (select 'A' as col from dual
  union
  select 'B' from dual
  union
  select 'C' from dual
  union
  select 'D' from dual
  union
  select 'E' from dual),

-- create child column
testdata2 as
 (select t.col as col1, t.col as col2 from testdata t)

select level, sys_connect_by_path(col1, '/') path
  from testdata2 t
connect by prior col1 < col2
 order by level, sys_connect_by_path(col1, '/');
```

result:

```
1   /A
1   /B
1   /C
1   /D
1   /E
2   /A/B
2   /A/C
2   /A/D
2   /A/E
2   /B/C
2   /B/D
2   /B/E
2   /C/D
2   /C/E
2   /D/E
3   /A/B/C
3   /A/B/D
3   /A/B/E
3   /A/C/D
3   /A/C/E
3   /A/D/E
3   /B/C/D
3   /B/C/E
3   /B/D/E
3   /C/D/E
4   /A/B/C/D
4   /A/B/C/E
4   /A/B/D/E
4   /A/C/D/E
4   /B/C/D/E
5   /A/B/C/D/E
```